# Как нажатием кнопки в кастомном ListView обратиться к элементам MainActivity?

Tags: java, android

Создал кастомный ListView с двумя кнопками.
В адаптере создал обработчик кнопок:

```
viewHolder.iv_edit_welding.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Он работает, т.е. правильно определяется position и какая из кнопок на ListView была нажата, но при попытке вызвать методы из MainActivity ругается, что они не статические и надо их сделать статическим. 
Можно ли как-то нажать на ListView программно из слушателя который я создал в адаптере? Или как-то по другому решить проблему?

Основная задача - нажав на одну из кнопок ListView как бы нажать на выбранный Item и дальнейшие шаги совершить в обработчике ListView в MainActivity но с условиями выбранных кнопок.

Comment: где находится данный listview? если он за пределами указанной вами активности то можно попробовать сделать через интерфейс, если же все в пределах одной активности то ругаться не должно

Comment: listview на активности, но как сэмулировать нажатие на нужный пункт listview? Вернее как нажать программно на нужный item?

Comment: что имеется в виду под эмуляцией? вы хотите программно нажать на какой-то пункт listview или что? не очень понятно если честно :)

Comment: да, хочу нажать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для программного выбора пункта списка можно воспользоваться такой конструкцией:

```
mListView.setItemChecked(1,true);
```

но нужно указывать это после того как вы присвоили адаптер списку. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788688/programmatically-select-item-listview-in-android) есть обсуждение по вашей теме. Но вообще если вы сделали адаптер и туда передаете данные, то можно просто в конструктор адаптера передать позицию "выбранного" пункта списка и в адаптере это обработать тоже можно будет.